# IntelliJ Cucumber.js test report shows reused steps only once

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, bdd, cucumberjs

I'm using Cucumber.js plugin to execute my features in IntelliJ. I noticed some problems.

I have a feature file with several scenarios. Some steps are reused between then. In the Tests Results I see some steps only once.

Example:

```
Feature: My Feature

Scenario: First
  Given some context
  When I perform action A
  Then I should get A results

Scenario: Second
  Given some context
  When I perform action B
  Then I should get B results
```

The Test Results will show the following:

```
Feature: My Feature    
    Scenario: First
      Step: some context
      Step: I perform action A
      Step: I should get A results

    Scenario: Second      
      Step: I perform action B
      Step: I should get B results
```

Notice that the given step is missing in the second scenario.

When I run cucumber.js in console - it's all fine.

Any suggestions?